# Getting Text between tags

Tags: c#, regex

Hey I have an input string that looks like this:

```
Just a test Post [c] hello world [/c]
```

the output should be:

> hello world

can anybody help?

I tried to use:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[c](.*)[/c]");
var v = regex.Match(post.Content);
string s = v.Groups[1].ToString();
```

Comment: I tried to use regex but it didn't work

Comment: you can test your regular expression online

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regex

```
[character_group]
```

means:

> Matches any single character in `character_group`.

Note that `\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #` and `white space` are [Character Escapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and you have to use `\` to use them in your expression:

```
\[c\](.*)\[/c\]
```

The backslash character `\` in a regular expression indicates that the character that follows it either is a special character, or should be interpreted literally.

so that your code should be work correctly if you edit your regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\[c\](.*)\[/c\]");
var v = regex.Match(post.Content);
string s = v.Groups[1].ToString();
```

Answer (score 12):

You may do this without `Regex`. Consider this extension method:

```
public static string GetStrBetweenTags(this string value, 
                                       string startTag, 
                                       string endTag)
{
    if (value.Contains(startTag) && value.Contains(endTag))
    {
        int index = value.IndexOf(startTag) + startTag.Length;
        return value.Substring(index, value.IndexOf(endTag) - index);
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

and use it:

```
string s = "Just a test Post [c] hello world [/c] ";
string res = s.GetStrBetweenTags("[c]", "[/c]");
```

Comment: See my improved version below

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[c\](.*)\[/c\]");
var v = regex.Match(post.Content);
string s = v.Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking on @horgh's answer, this adds an inclusive/exclusive option:

```
public static string ExtractBetween(this string str, string startTag, string endTag, bool inclusive)
{
    string rtn = null;

    int s = str.IndexOf(startTag);
    if (s >= 0)
    {
        if(!inclusive)
            s += startTag.Length;

        int e = str.IndexOf(endTag, s);
        if (e > s)
        {
            if (inclusive)
                e += startTag.Length;

            rtn = str.Substring(s, e - s);
        }
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You looking for something like this?

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\[c\]).*?(?=\[/c\])");
foreach(Match match in regex.Matches(someString))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code takes into account also identical opening tags and can ignore tag case

```
 public static string GetTextBetween(this string value, string startTag, string endTag, StringComparison stringComparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            int startIndex = value.IndexOf(startTag, stringComparison) + startTag.Length;
            if (startIndex > -0)
            {
                var endIndex = value.IndexOf(endTag, startIndex, stringComparison);
                if (endIndex > 0)
                {
                    return value.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```